# Redirecting the output of a script into a file?

Tags: bash, scripting, output

I want the user to be able to name a file to be created, and then have the output of the script redirected to that file. The script will create a long listing of a directory and count the number of files in that directory. This is what I have so far:

```
echo -n "Please enter the name of a file to be created: "

read FILENAME

touch FILENAME

ls -l exampledir

echo

ls -l exampledir | wc -l
```

I might not be using read correctly, I'm not too sure.

*Edit*

I figured most of it out, here is the new code:

```
echo -n "Please enter the name of a file to be created: "

read FILENAME

ls -l Assign_7 > FILENAME

echo >> FILENAME

ls -l Assign_7 | wc -l >> FILENAME
```

The only thing I can't figure out is how to get the file to be named what the user entered. It has the right stuff inside, but right now the file is always called FILENAME

*2nd EDIT*

Figured it out. Just needed to add $ before each FILENAME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple:

```
#/bin/bash
echo -n "Please enter the name of a file to be created: "

read FILENAME

ls -l Assign_7 > $FILENAME
echo >> $FILENAME
ls -l Assign_7 | wc -l >> $FILENAME
```

This is called `Parameter Expansion`, see `man bash` for complete explanation.

Also, there is a bit shorter form that simplifies the script a bit and makes the `bash` to open an output file only once:

```
#/bin/bash
echo -n "Please enter the name of a file to be created: "

read FILENAME

exec > $FILENAME
ls -l Assign_7
echo ""
ls -l Assign_7 | wc -l
```

This latter form does redirection of the current shell's `stdout` to a file by executing `exec > $FILENAME` command, thus the output of all subsequent commands the shell executes is also directed to that file.